# How do I align a pgfplots graph?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a graph with the associated table of data using pgfplots. It works great, but the graph itself isn't aligned with the table. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I don't like the overhang. **How can I move the position of the graph?**

I would like to either line up one side or another. This is what it would look like if I could line them up to the right:

[image]

I could deal with only being able to do that, but it would also be useful to have a more general way to move the graph.

I've looked around in the pgfplots manual, as well as the [pgf manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), but I couldn't find anything that looked  promising. I'm fairly new to LaTeX, only been using it for a few days, so feel free to just point me in the right direction.

Code:

```
Results:\\
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \textbf{QP} & \textbf{Average PSNR\_Y ($dB$)} & \textbf{Total bits} \\
    \hline
    1 & 49.197166 & 14593504\\
    \hline
    8 & 32.003399 & 1106824\\
    \hline
    16 & 28.387211 & 374880\\
    \hline
    24 & 26.661640 & 206704\\
    \hline
    31 & 25.740038 & 150056\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{2em}


\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$QP$,
        ylabel={$Encoding Quality$}
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
%   \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1,49.197166)
        (8,32.003399)
        (16,28.387211)
        (24,26.661640)
        (31,25.740038)
    };
    \addlegendentry{ PSNR\_Y }
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1,58.374016)
        (8,4.427296)
        (16,1.49952)
        (24,0.826816)
        (31,0.600224)

    };
    \addlegendentry{Total Bits $\times250,000$}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$QP$,
        ylabel={$Encoding Quality$},
        at=(current page.west),
        shift={(10.8em,-13em)},
    ]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The exam sheet example [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/absolute-positioning/) shows a little more. Page 198 of the [pgf manual](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) has some more information about `remember picture, overlay`. Using these commands along with `\vspace*{}` will give you as much control as you want. You can use `px` or any other standard units in the `shift` coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

I think the `trim right` and `trim left` options are only useful if there is something which sticks out of the axis' box -- for example, if you want to exclude a legend from the horizontal alignment.

In your case, it appears to me that it suffices to surround the table and the graphics with

```
\begin{flushright}
...
\end{flushright}
```

If you have multiple elements which you want to align, you can also pack all of them into a tabular (which supports left-aligned or right-aligned columns in a natural way).

Once you start with horizontal *and* vertical alignment, you should consider using the `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]` option and the `\begin{tabular}[c]` flag as well -- both are part of the associated control mechanisms (which are explained in more detail in the pgfplots manual, there is a section "Alignment" somewhere which should also cover these specific cases).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `trim left` and `trim right` options.

Eg.  you should write:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=0cm]
 ...plot code...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

See also the [pgf manual](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), page 167 for a description on how to use it correctly. Basically what it does is ignore everything that is left of the given `trim left` *x*-coordinate and right of the `trim right` coordinate.

So in the above example, everything to the left of *x=0* is ignored for the bounding box.

Play around with it till you get the results you want.

Comment: When I add trim and try to compile I get an emergency stop. I tried copy/pasting the example from the pgf manual, and got an error too.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: That's all the info it gives me - Emergency stop, and exit with errorcode 1

Comment: don't know what that means sorry, try the answer below or submit a MWE so I can help you furthur.

Answer (score 1):

How do you insert the graph and the table?If you wrote

```
\begin{table}...\end{table}\\    
\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
```

try with

```
\begin{table}...\end{table}\\  
\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This worked for my my first graph - For this particular table and graph it looks good, but I've got another one that it doesn't work so well for.

Comment: If the code is similar it should work the same way. If not, please show the differences